# MVVM Windows Phone 8 - adding a collection of pushpins to a map

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, bing-maps, pushpin

Here is the XAML code:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="NearbyMap" 
                  Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
              >
        <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
            <maptk:MapItemsControl Name="StoresMapItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Treks}">
                <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <maptk:Pushpin x:Name="RouteDirectionsPushPin" GeoCoordinate="{Binding Location}" Visibility="Visible" Content="test"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </maptk:MapItemsControl>
            <maptk:UserLocationMarker x:Name="UserLocationMarker" Visibility="Visible" GeoCoordinate="{Binding MyLocation}"/>
        </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>

xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
xmlns:maptk="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

**PushPinModel** has an attribute Location which is a GeoCoordinate. **Treks** is an `ObservableCollection<PushPinModel>`. I run this code and only the **UserLocationMarker** is displayed, which is my current location.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally make it work by using dependency property. I added a new class:

```
public static class MapPushPinDependency
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
             "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MapPushPinDependency),
             new PropertyMetadata(OnPushPinPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnPushPinPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uie = (UIElement)d;
        var pushpin = MapExtensions.GetChildren((Map)uie).OfType<MapItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
        pushpin.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)e.NewValue;
    }


    #region Getters and Setters

    public static IEnumerable GetItemsSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (IEnumerable)obj.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetItemsSource(DependencyObject obj, IEnumerable value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And in the .xaml file I have added

```
xmlns:dp="clr-namespace:Treks.App.Util.DependencyProperties"
```

and now the .xaml file looks like this:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="NearbyMap" 
                  Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  dp:MapPushPinDependency.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Treks}"
              >
        <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
            <maptk:MapItemsControl Name="StoresMapItemsControl">
                <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <maptk:Pushpin x:Name="PushPins" GeoCoordinate="{Binding Location}" Visibility="Visible" Content="test"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </maptk:MapItemsControl>
            <maptk:UserLocationMarker x:Name="UserLocationMarker" Visibility="Visible" GeoCoordinate="{Binding MyLocation}"/>
        </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>
```

Now all the pushpins are correctly rendered.

Comment: Could you also provide code for the Page.xaml.cs - I don't know how I can bind the actual list of map items (i.e. `Tracks`) to the `Map` or `MapItemsControl`

Comment: solved my problem, I couldn't access the MapItemsControl with the name: `ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(NearbyMap);
            MapItemsControl mapItems = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(MapItemsControl)) as MapItemsControl;
            mapItems.ItemsSource = Treks;`

Answer (score 3):

The `MapItemsControl` is currently not yet MVVM bindable ( what I am aware off ).
So best way is to set it's `ItemsSource` in the code behind of your view.

You can still use the collection defined in your ViewModel though!
Options are:

- through mvvm messaging pass along the collection from the viewmodel to the code behind of the view
- use the datacontext of the view to access the collection, something like this: `this.StoresMapItemsControl.ItemsSource = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>().Locations;`