# Problems getting a collection of points to display with Nokia Maps

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

I am working with the Nokia Maps control in Windows Phone 8.  Here is the code I have at present (relevant parts only)

C#

```
public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> ItemLocations
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>()
                {
                    new LocationViewModel()
                        {
                            Display = "MVVM Test",
                            Location = new GeoCoordinate(43.07441, -88.25609)
                        }
                };
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<maps:Map Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
              ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel}">
        <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
            <maptk:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemLocations}">
                <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <maptk:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Location}" Content="{Binding Display}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </maptk:MapItemsControl>
        </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>
```

Right now, when the Map page loads, it centers on the correct location, however, no matter what I do with the ItemLocations list I get no points displayed on the Map. I went ahead and statically defined maptk:MapItemsControl.Items with some static points and it worked fine, it is only when I attempt binding (shown above) that it fails.

The solution is utilizing Caliburn Micro for MVVM. As you can see with the sample above, I have hard coded the locations list in the ViewModel but *get* is never called, which is mysterious to me. If I only define PushPins as children to MapExtensions.Children it works.

I am starting to wonder if ItemsSource is not bindable, but I feel that would be ridiculous.  Help please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as you and took me some time to solve it. Check this [MVVM Windows Phone 8 - adding a collection of pushpins to a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417978/mvvm-windows-phone-8-adding-a-collection-of-pushpins-to-a-map/16441672#16441672) maybe this gonna help you, too.

Comment: Very nice - I gave you a Vote Up for it on that page as well