# How to use a specific google map with WP8 Maps control - C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps, pins

I want to use this map: http://www.subway.com/storelocator/ with all the subway restaurant positions in my map on Windows Phone 8. I know how to find out the position of the phone and how to zoom in, but I don't know how I can bind in these subway positions. Thanks for any helpful answer.

Comment: Please edit your question and choose a title that describes your problem. "C# - WP8 - Use a google map" carries no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question and the original title, I assume you're not actually trying to use Google maps on WP but rather provide your users with the ability to search for Subway store locations within your app? If so, what you really need is the way to get the store locations, which you can do by calling [**Subway's store location webservice**](http://www.subway.com/webservices/js-storelocator/wsvclocator.asmx?op=GetLocations), and then [**fill and bind the pushpin collection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417978/mvvm-windows-phone-8-adding-a-collection-of-pushpins-to-a-map) using natively supported Bing maps control.

If I have misunderstood and you are asking how to use Google maps (or rather Google map tiles in the WP Maps control), I'm not sure that's entirely legal. See 10.1.1. in the [**terms of use**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).

If you don't need to access or manipulate the store locations data in any way and only want to provide an in-app experience for the app users, you can also simply embed the WebBrowser control and navigate to the store locator page.

Comment: The first link is perfect! Thanks! And yes I used the wrong words to describe my problem :D

Comment: Are there any samples for using HTTP GET and get the response with the coordinates of this webservice?

Comment: You can use Fiddler to capture the traffic between the store locator page and the service, then emulate it from your app.